# Hacer login en web mediante cURL

Tags: php, login, curl

Estoy intentando hacer login en una web mediante cURL en PHP para posteriormente hacer web scraping de la página resultante al logearse. Estoy empleando el siguiente código:

```
<?php

    $url = 'URL en la que quiero logearme';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $parametros_post = 'ips_username='.urlencode("nombre de Usuario").'&ips_password='.urlencode("contraseña").'&rememberMe='.urlencode("1").'&anonymous='.urlencode("1");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros_post);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);

    //Guardar página
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //Comprobar si ha hecho login en la página
    echo $result;
?>
```

Aclaraciones:

- Como `$url` he usado lo que aparece en la página dentro del campo "action" del `<form>` de logueo.
- En la variable `$parametros_post` he incluído todos los campos `<input>` del formulario que tuviesen etiqueta "name" con el valor de mi usuario o en su defecto con el valor que apareciese en su etiqueta "value".
- El botón de submit no contenía etiqueta "name", por lo que no lo he incluído en la variable `$parametros_post` (aunque sí contenía type, class, value y tabIndex, no sé si influirá en algo).
- Estoy usando un localhost a través de WampServer con Apache y PHP 5.4.3.
- Las cookies deben de estar mal configuradas ya que al arrancar el archivo .php en mi localhost me aparece `Notice: Undefined variable: cookie_file`.
- Al abrir el archivo .php en localhost, en la propia página web a la que intento loguearme  aparece un mensaje diciendo `Sorry, you don't have permission for that. We encountered a problem precessing your login request`, es decir, que al procesar la peticion php en vez de enviarme a la página de inicio ya logueado me envían a una página de error, supongo que por no tener bien configuradas las cookies.
- La página a la que intento loguearme es https, por si sirve o cambia algo las cosas.

Comment: Quizas sea que pedis las cookies pero no la estas almacenando.avisame si funciona